# Rails model/field naming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-4, naming-conventions, field

I'm about to add a model to my app and I was inclined to call it "collection". It was also to have a field called "status" but it occurred to me that I think Rails uses both those terms elsewhere and this might be a problem worth avoiding.

Should I pick another model name instead of collection? and would state be better than status?

Thanks.

Comment: Using status as a term is definitely fine. Used it many times myself before. Also `:collection` is just (to my knowledge) used in certain view helpers, for which it wouldn't be an issue anyways.

Comment: I use 'options_from_collection_for_select' quite a lot in forms. Can you see that being a problem if I had a model with the same name?

Comment: No. The only problem with this would be if there was a helper method named `options_for_#{model_name}_for_select`, which there isn't.

Comment: Thank you, I shall go ahead as planned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used both before - I think you should use whatever makes most sense to you, that aren't reserved words.  If you think they will conflict with logic elsewhere in your app, then you might consider a different model name and/or column name.